# Line graph in Report Builder duplicating X-axis dates

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I am attempting to create a line graph in Report Builder using the following data:

```
TRWR    rental  85805   2013-09-14 13:02:54.900
TRWR    rental  74415   2013-09-15 18:00:00.420
VRWR    rental  83017   2013-09-14 10:03:43.597
VRWR    rental  73984   2013-09-15 18:00:01.203
HRWR    rental  83017   2013-09-14 14:03:15.497
HRWR    rental  74005   2013-09-15 18:00:01.957
```

And the query that I am using is the following:

```
select ServerName, DatabaseName, FileSizeMB, DISTINCT PollDate from DBinfo
where DatabaseName IN (@Database) AND ServerName IN(@Servers) AND PollDate Between @StartDate AND @EndDate AND PhysicalFileName LIKE ('%mdf')
```

However, when I attempt to create the chart the X axis (dates) are duplicating. This is how I've set it up. Can anyone please show me how I can enter distinct dates. Please see the link for the image: http://imgur.com/7nhP3B6

Answer (score 0):

Well even though it is not the best method for determining duplicates it gets the job done generally.  I would guess the first step in debugging your method is your dataset is actually returning duplicates.  You can avoid this by merely stating:

Select DISTINCT ....

versus

Select .....

This is merely SQL syntax telling the database engine to list a distinct row for each result.

Comment: Its not returning duplicates because the First column and the dates are different.

Comment: Your grouping in the chart is wrong then.  In your image you show the second drow down field 'Category Groups' the default behavior of SSRS on a chart is when you add a generic group it will aggregate on that.  You can hit the dropdown and see under 'General' what it is 'Group on:' and if this is valid DATETIME field it should list distinctly unless the data is no aggregating properly.  If your data is not grouping properly you could add an expression like '=DAY(Fields!(fieldName).value) and this will force a daily aggregate of the data.